# How to disable toggling a line breakpoint in PyCharm while clicking on the line number?

Tags: pycharm, breakpoints, jetbrains-ide

I would like to disable toggling line breakpoint by cliking on line number. I have checked PyCharm's [breakpoint documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-breakpoints.html#set-breakpoints), but haven't found anything useful. PyCharm's version is `PyCharm 2023.2 (Community Edition), Build #PC-232.8660.197, built on July 26, 2023`.

The reason for the question is simple: I have bad clicking precision and sometimes when I want to (un-)fold code block, I missclick and activate line breakpoint.

[Example of me missclicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LJvr.gif)

P.S.: Line breakpoint can be still toggled with <kbd>Ctrl + F8</kbd>, but in general there is no need for debugging specifically in my current project.